# How to know the server name of SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 on my machine. 
I want to connect with Windows authentication mode. 
I dont remember the server name....I have also checked in SQL Server Configuration 
Manager but there is no instance running. 
so , How to know the serve name of SQL server ?

Comment: Go to Services on the machine and make sure `SQL Server (instance_name)` service is running. Then use `local\instance_name`  from SSMS to connect to it locally or `ipAddress\instance_name` from the network.

Answer (score 1):

did you try

```
 SELECT @@SERVERNAME
```

Comment: where should I type this ?

Comment: At the sqlcomd prompt. If your server is running on the same machine, you shoud be able a start a Diagnostic Connection for Database Administrators.

Answer (score 0):

Open Regedit and navigate to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server
```

You'll see instances listed there with names taking the form

```
MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS
```

MSSQL10 is the version number (10 applies to both 2008 and 2008R2) and the part after the period is the instance name. That gives you a server name of

```
MYCOMPUTER\INSTANCENAME
```

Comment: Then you probably haven't got SQL Server installed on your PC. If there's nothing there and nothing in configuration manager then it's been uninstalled most likely. You could try running the 2008 R2 setup. If you have an instance that will find it and ask if you want to repair it or do something else. If it's not there then you can re-install.

Answer (score -2):

The name will always be your PC name which you can find by right clicking your "My Computer" and going to properties.

Comment: Name can be specified during installation and it's not necessarily the same as machine name.

Comment: I'm not convinced it can? The instance name can be configured but I don't think the server name can be?